# How to restart a service each hour?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, startup

I have a service I need to restart every hour. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I don't really seem to find a script suitable restarting a service based on a prefixed time setting. How do I restart the service automatically through a script?

Comment: You can use [*cron*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

Comment: Why not fix it so that it doesn't need restarting in the first place?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to monkey patch something instead of actually fixing the issues you are having...

Comment: @whiners - sometimes you can't spend weeks to debug code of broken services

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open crontab by command:

```
crontab -e
```

To run a command every 60 minutes:

```
*/60 * * * * /path/to/command
```

Replace  /path/to/command with command to restart service.

It may look like this when you want to restart mysql:

```
*/60 * * * * service mysqld restart
```

More information can be found at http://www.ubuntututorials.com/use-crontab-ubuntu/

Comment: `crontab -e` edits the user's crontab, not the system-wide crontab. Is it ok to run a service from this crontab schedule? Will it be run with the required privileges?

Comment: You can specify a specific user with `-u` flag. For your concern about required privileges, you can run with root user `crontab -u root -e`.